# Tika and Solr Drupal 7 Indexing on Cron

Tags: drupal, search, solr, attachment, apache-tika

Using Drupal/Search API module/Solr/Tika we are trying to index a large number of files.

I've set up the index and everything works fine until I include the Search API attachments module.

When we run cron, `tika` is not being called. We know this because we put in a snippet of PHP code to write to the system log at the end of the tika module and that message never shows up. It does show up when running the index manually.

Additionally, the number of items index does not go up after a cron run.

We also noticed that if we run tika from the command line we get the following error at the top of the output:
INFO - unsupported/disabled operation: EI

The index works as expected without checking the box to index attachments both on cron and by manually indexing.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Site Built On:

- Drupal 7

Modules In Question:

- Search API
- Search API Attachments

Indexing with:

- Apache Solr

Indexing Attachments using:

- Tika Library

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But it does not seem to be a problem at all, because the document seems to get indexed anyway.

I guess it is a Tika problem, because some documents (pdf) are working well, others not. Maybe it depends on the pdf version. Try something more simple. I.E. I wrote a sample text and used the print to pdf function on my mac to get a simple pdf document. Or use a Word doc. We also had to apply the [real-path patch](http://drupal.org/node/1148162) to get Tika working with the files ... and the [transliteration](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration) module to have clean filenames. For debugging search_api I use dd()-function from devel. In search_api_solr/includes/solr_httptransport.inc performHttpRequest() I call 
`dd($url); dd($options);` right before `$response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);` (line:92) ... hopefully this helps.